# MULE error [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm getting the following error while trying to run my MULE project in MuleStudio 3.5.  I was running the same project 2 weeks ago and have not made any changes to this particular project.  The only thing I've done is add a new project to the workspace.  If I try to run the new project I get the same error.  I also tried removing the new project, but that didn't work.  However, I have other projects in the workspace that are working fine.  Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'max_nd_max_workorders'                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:03,741 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:03,920 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleApplicationContext@1f2586d6: startup date [Thu Jun 16 09:43:03 MDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:09,353 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: httpMaxWOPollingConnector
WARN  2016-06-16 09:43:09,475 [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor: Invalid JavaBean property 'port' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.mule.endpoint.URIBuilder.setPort(int)]
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:12,439 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising model: _muleSystemModel
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:12,573 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: httpConnector
INFO  2016-06-16 09:43:12,611 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising connector: httpProxyConnector
org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:110)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:119)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:57)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)


INFO  2016-06-15 13:50:48,189 [main]   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'max_nd_pm_workorders' never started, nothing to dispose of
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalArgumentException:
```

mule-deploy.properties:

```
   redeployment.enabled=true
   encoding=UTF-8
   domain=default
   config.resources=max_nd_max_workorders.xml
```

Comment: Also, the output of the error in the console does not seem to be helpful.  I've found other posts with the same error, but more explicit on the reason.

Comment: all I can think of is cleaning target folder. Check Run configurations and see if u r passing any arguments

Comment: Share your mule-deploy properties file

Comment: I edited my post with the mule-deploy.properties and added the initialization portion before the error occurred.

Comment: Also, I had already cleaned the target folder and there are no arguments being passed in the Run config.

Comment: Please share the app XML config.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across same situation and I did not think of justifying any solution to the same. Also I don't remember any fixed solution that rectified the issue. Please try any of the following approaches which solved this issue for me.

- Check if the mule-deploy.properties does not have extra spaces or line breaks and make sure all the needed properties are correct
- Check if you have not used same port number or same connector twice
- Check if you have not used two http listners by mistake as I don't see this is supported in the new Versions of Mule(3.6 and above)
- Clear / delete the .metadata and the .mule folder in the work-space
- For above items you need to re import all the projects as "import project from folder location " again . Make sure you uncheck the copy project to work space

If nothing works then take a new anypoint studio installation and then import all your projects to that in a new workspace.

Comment: Please let me know which of the above worked for you. One of them worked for me sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue with mule server 3.8.3 EE. Got fixed by downgrading to 3.7.0 EE