# Error when setting 'maxThreadsActive' on anypoint MQ

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to set "maxThreadsActive" to 1 , to make sure there is only one thread pulling messages form queue , but for some reason i am getting sax parse exception in compile time .
Following is the Configuration :

```
    <anypoint-mq:config name="Anypoint_MQ_Configuration"
    provider-ref="anypointMQ_Provider_Settings" doc:name="Anypoint MQ Configuration" >
    <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
</anypoint-mq:config>
```

error :

```
ERROR 2017-10-04 12:35:00,849 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
```

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'http:worker-threading-profile'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls":context, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":proxy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/anypoint-mq":provider, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/anypoint-mq":prefetch, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/anypoint-mq":worker-threading-profile}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

Comment: Validator clearly tells that you are using wrong namespace there, just replace "http" with "anypoint-mq" .

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the Anypoint Studio.
The anypoint-mq connector configuration from Studio creates a internal tag with http:worker-threading-profile, which is not a valid child element for the anypoint-mq:config element.

To fix the error, you need to manually update the XML file by removing the http:worker-threading-profile, and add the following child element 'anypoint-mq:worker-threading-profile'. If you add this element, then it would not be shown in the Studio, but it will set the Thread profiling to Anypoint MQ connector.

This is an error with Studio.

Please refer the following link and go to section 'Threading Profile Settings'
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/anypoint-mq-connector-reference

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be missing some configurations, do check the following SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904111/7141847

And if you are setting **maxThreadsActive** to **1** i believe you need to set **poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"** in anypoint-mq-configurations

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I have faced the similar issue.To ressolve this we need to use updated anypoint mq connector for the AnypointStudio-version(6.6.0).

**Studio & Mq version**

[image]